# Where's the file pst-arrows?

Tags: pstricks

I'm trying to compile an image done with pstricks but everytime I run it I get the message "I can't find the file 'pst-arrow. ...rrowLoaded\endinput\else\input pst-arrow'"

The thing is... a long time ago I run this code and it was fine. Now I have to modify it but this message keep showing up. And I did not even change anything. I used the pstrick-add package. Thought this would be enough.

I'm using texmaker with MikTex 2.9. Can somebody help me?

Thank you.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\textheight=25cm
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\psset{arrowscale=3}

% Lines (\psline macro)

 \begin{pspicture}(2,1)
 \psline[ArrowInside=->]{<->}(2,1)
 \end{pspicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: How are you loading `pst-arrow`? Are you only loading `pstricks-add`? Please provide a minimal example that replicates the current erroneous behaviour. Note that there was [a recent change](http://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.7.1472898578.1426.ctan-ann@ctan.org) in terms of [`pst-arrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-arrow). All the arrow-related code was removed from [`pstricks-add`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks-add).

Comment: I included \usepackage{pst-arrow} and still nothing. Do you have any idea where in the miktek file should the arrow.sty be?

Answer (score 6):

As @Werner pointed in his comment, there has been a recent change in the organisation of `pstricks-add`. You should install `pst-arrow` via MiKTeX Package Manager. Don't forget to synchronise the Package Repository first:

[image]

Comment: I looked for pst-arrow in the package manager but nothing shows up.

Comment: Go to `Package Repository` and ask to `Synchronise` to update the database of packages. Probably also launch the `Update manager`.

Comment: If you have any other problems, you might need to update your MikTeX installation. Use the "MikTeX Update (Admin)" application to do that. It is possible you will have to run this update twice until it is fully updated.